# Querying Document in salesforce

Tags: soql

```
[SELECT AuthorId.Name FROM Document]
```

I am getting error in executing the above query.

> INVALID_FIELD: 
>   Select AuthorId.Name FROM Document

I want to get the name of the author of the document.

Comment: I've never actually queried the Document table, but have you tried Author.Name?

Comment: @NickCook or OP mind turning that into an actual answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `AuthorId.Name`, try `Author.Name`

A similar scenario exists with ProfileId and probably a few other fields.